# WCF odd behavior: application/xml but JSON body in request

Tags: c#, xml, json, wcf

I have an endpoint defined:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IRequestStuff
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "token", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    ResponseData RequestStuff(RequestData request);
}
```

I call it via this:

```
using (var f = new WebChannelFactory<IRequestStuff>(new Uri("http://myhost/TestService/RequestStuff.svc")))
{
    var request = new RequestData()
    {
        Member1 = "Member 1",
        Member2 = "Member 2"
    };

    var response = f.CreateChannel().RequestStuff(request);
}
```

I also have a listening web service endpoint at the specified location.
Everything works fine when I try to call from a test app. But, when I call RequestStuff from inside another web service, the request has the strangest of things - it has "Content-Type: application/xml", but the body is JSON {"Member1" : "Member 1", "Member2" : "Member 2"}.

Naturally, the endpoint returns Bad Request, because the request is malformed.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WCF 4.0 then  you can enable `automaticFormatSelectionEnabled` property of the `WebHttpBehavior`. Check out [this](http://www.topwcftutorials.net/2014/02/automatic-format-selection-wcf-restful-service.html) for more detail.

Comment: Where do I enable it? Will this affect the way the request looks? For some reason, the request says the application/xml, but it has JSON body.

Comment: Check out the link mention in answer http://www.topwcftutorials.net/2014/02/automatic-format-selection-wcf-restful-service.html

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, that in this particular case, I have to create a new OperationContextScope to place an outbound request. Maybe it is because the caller and the called services reside on the same host.

```
using (var f = new WebChannelFactory<IRequestStuff>(new Uri("http://myhost/TestService/RequestStuff.svc")))
{
    var request = new RequestData()
    {
        Member1 = "Member 1",
        Member2 = "Member 2"
    };

    var intf = f.CreateChannel();

    using (new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)intf))
    {
        var response = intf.RequestStuff(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json` from `WebInvoke` attribute. Also enabling auto format selection as mentioned above might be useful:

```
f.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior
{
     AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled = true
});
var intf = f.CreateChannel();
```